# Spring Caching: evict entry remotely

Tags: spring, caching, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cache

I have 2 microservices both reading/writing the same database. In one of them, I cache the results of REST-endpoint for some entities. I also have `@CachePut` and `@CacheEvict` there to control entities lifecycle.

Now, the second microservice comes into the picture: it also can modify entities, returned by the first one.

My question is: is there any mechanism for remote cache entry eviction in this case? Of course, I can do it manually by exposing "reset" endpoint in the first microservice and calling it from the second one. But I am hoping there's some built-in mechanism for that, maybe in Spring Cloud.

Comment: I would avoid having microservices knowing about caches managed by other microservices, let alone taking responsibility for evicting cache entries by calling an exposed service.  Possible architectural violations aside (multiple services sharing database entities?), why wouldn't this be asynchronous, event-based?  Something happened (I modified something), and the service publishes that fact.  Anyone interested can respond to that event, including managing its own caches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a cache replication solution would be a good way to go. Any change `service 1` makes in its cache would be replicated to the cache of `service 2` and vice versa, over TCP/UDP - depending on your config.

There are multiple cache providers(e.g. EHCache) which provide this out of the box.

---

My config looks something like this:

`...

<!-- Set up Cache peer provider factory -->
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheManagerPeerProviderFactory" propertySeparator="," properties="replicateAsynchronously=true,replicatePuts=true,replicateUpdates=true,replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false,replicateRemovals=true"/>

<!-- Set up Cache peer listener factory -->
<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"/>

...`

---

Look into [this (EHCache replication)](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/replication/) - might be helpful.

Comment: Sounds promising! Did you actually test it with Spring Cache API, including `@CachePut` and `@CacheEvict` annotations?

Comment: Yes, currently running multiple instances on same box, via UDP autoconfig. Works fine with entire spring cache suite.